# No module named examples.tutorials.mnist

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow

I started tensorflow first, and I was reading tutorials for beginner.

In window, so I used Oracle VM VirtualBox, and I installed by pip virtualenv through https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#virtualenv-installation

and, I checked tensorflow working well by compiling "`import tensorflow by tf`" with no error.

But, during tutorial, I had error in tutorial code

> no module named examples.tutorials.mnist,

at "`from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data`".

I can't find why it has like this error... isn't that code for downloading MNIST data?

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10])) # weight
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10])) # bias

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue, but I was running it naively on Windows (Tensor Flow for Windows was released in November 2016). The problem for me was that I was trying to run it using the wrong version of Python.

I had installed Python v3.5 for Tensor flow in addition to Python 2.7 (for other work) using [pylauncer](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher). Python 3.5 is required to run Tensor Flow on windows. I had Python 2.7 as my default, so when I tried to run it, I would get errors caused by it running it with the wrong version of python. In order to force it to use Python 3, I ran the command `py -3 tf_tutorial.py` as opposed to `python tf_tutorial.py`.

Not sure if this will help you. But hopefully someone with this issue finds this useful.